# matlabpool open stalls and states distcomp error

Tags: java, matlab, parallel-processing, matlabpool

I want to test parallel code execution on matlab and started by typing

```
matlabpool open
```

which caused matlab to not respond, but when I stopped it by Crtl-C after 20min it said:

"Error using matlabpool (line 136) Failed to open matlabpool. (For information in addition to the causing error, validate the configuration 'local' in the Configurations Manager.)

Caused by: Error using distcomp.interactiveclient/pGetSockets "

What happened before: Earlier today (the first time I used it) it started up ok; then I ran into a problem with parfor, set up two other configurations, deleted them again, and closed matlabpool. Now with reopening it, it gave me the problem above.

Any ideas what to do? Does it pertain to a java problem?

Comment: "validate the configuration 'local' in the Configurations Manager." Did you try it? What was the result? Did you restart your PC? Might be that crashed workers are still open locking the ports.

Comment: After restarting the PC it worked! Thanks! Is there a way to get there without restarting? Or should I not create the other configurations?

Comment: The problem was the crashing, with multiple working configurations everything is fine.

Comment: So crashing means the Crtl-C? But it did not respond before I pressed that, already.